# Obtener href de un div en Selenium con Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Estoy probando Seleniun en Python y me he encontrado con un problema. La idea que tengo consiste en obtener dos listas en las cuales insertaré el nombre de las series mejor valoradas y por otro lado el enlace a la página de dichas serie. Las seriese encuentran en la web en una lista con el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De estos campos los únicos que me interesan son donde pone

He estado intentando obtener dichos campos pero únicamente he podido conseguir el nombre de la serie pero el link me resulta imposible, os dejo por aquí mi código

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/topgen.php?genre=TV_SE&fromyear=&toyear=2019&country=&nodoc")


html_list_serie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-movies"]')


html_elements_peliculas = html_list_serie.find_elements_by_class_name("mc-title")

nombreSerie = []
linkSerie = []

for item in html_elements_serie:
    nombreSerie.append(item.text)
    linkSerie.append(item.find_element_by_tag_name('href'))
```

Con este código si luego hago un print de ambas listas, la que contiene el nombre si que me los tiene almacenados pero en la de los links me aparece "None". Lo que no entiendo de esto es que ambas listas tienen 30 elementos (se corresponden al rank de las 30 mejores series) y en la lista de links hay 30 None.

Espero que me puedan ayudar,

Un saludo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quiere es obtener los `href` y los `titulos`. Una posibilidad podría ser de la siguiente manera:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('movie-card').find_element_by_class_name('mc-info-container').find_element_by_class_name('mc-title').find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')

>>'https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film399474.html'


browser.find_element_by_class_name('movie-card').find_element_by_class_name('mc-info-container').find_element_by_class_name('mc-title').find_element_by_tag_name('a').text

>>'The Wire (Bajo escucha) (Serie de TV)'
```

**Actualización**

Al querer tomar la lista de 30 elementos tenemos que utilizar `find_elements`. De la siguiente manera puede ser una opción:

```
#obtenemos el elemento donde se encuentran los items.
ELEMENT_TOP_MOVIES = browser.find_element_by_id('top-movies')
#Una vez dentro del elemento, vamos bajando hasta encontrar la etiqueta
LI = ELEMENT_TOP_MOVIES.find_elements_by_class_name('content')
```

Luego con un bucle iteramos todos los elementos que contienen la clase "content". Y buscamos lo que necesitamos, en este caso el `titulo` de la pelicula y el `href`. Y finalmente lo guardamos en una `lista de listas`, donde se puede acceder por su posición a cada elemento.

```
LISTA_PELICULAS = []
for i in LI:

    LISTA_PELICULAS.append([i.find_element_by_class_name('mc-title').text,
         i.find_element_by_class_name('mc-title').find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')])
```

**Bonus Track**

Como la página nos muestra un `boton` abajo, nos esta diciendo que hay más 30 "productos/peliculas", al hacer `click` se cargan más. Entonces podemos divertirnos con `Selenium` y vamos a clickear...

Desconozco hasta donde se llega haciendo `scroll` en esta página, así que a modo práctico, utilizaré un contador para que pueda pararlo en cierto punto.

```
TIEMPO_DE_ESPERA = 10.5
CORTAR=0

last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")


while True:

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(TIEMPO_DE_ESPERA)
    try:
        #boton para cargar más items
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="load-more-bt"]/i').click()
        CORTAR+=1
    except:
        pass

    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

    if CORTAR == 6:
        break
```

De esta manera, estamos aprovechando `Selenium`para hacer `click` y cargar más productos, ahora podemos volver a ejecutar el código que obtiene los productos, y la lista será mayor a 30 productos.

pd: Si quieres saber hasta donde llega, solo tienes que quitar la variable `CORTAR`

Comment: El problema es que eso solo funciona para un elemento y mi propósito es que funcionase para todas las series de la página actual, es decir, obtener una lista con los 30 nombres de las series y otra lista distinta con los 30 links, de esa forma puedo trabajar luego con ellos más cómodamente

Comment: Vale, entendí mal, en ese caso, usariamos `find_elements`. Editaré mi respuesta en breve para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Genial!! Ahora si que funciona!! Muchísimas gracias :D